# How do I save my overscan value in Nvidia-settings on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-settings, overscan

Well as the title says, I'd like to know how I can save the value of my overscan compensation (value is between 0 and 200) after reboot on Ubuntu 11.10. The graphics card I have is an Nvidia ION. I'd really like it so that it works without me having to do anything once I've set it. It's always needing the overscan value 100, so would like to have it as that. 
I've tried [this fix](http://judsonsnotes.com/notes/index.PHP?option=com_content&view=article&id=526:fixing-overscan-again&catid=37:tech-notes&Itemid=59) to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

Additional information:
The setting for the compensation value is found under GPU-0 - (ION) tree item in the x server settings, and appears to be separate from the x Screen setting

Comment: Just by the way, why aren't you looking for an answer that works?

Comment: @wizlog - Not sure what you mean. I **AM** looking for an answer that works. Unfortunately I'm at a loss since nobody seems to know the answer to how to save these settings correctly

Comment: When you used "[this fix](http://judsonsnotes.com/notes/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=526%3afixing-overscan-again&catid=37%3atech-notes&Itemid=59)" did you add/change any other lines of code?

Comment: Are you changing the overscan value to be used with a TV, if so, please provide a link to manufacture's website, or a model number.

Comment: The model is the Nvidia Ion 2 - The Tv is a Goodmans, although it's not possible to do the compensation via the TV (I've tried everything). The nvidia compensation works, its just that I have to change the setting every time I boot the computer manually, and don't want to have to do this

Comment: For the "this fix" - I only made the changes described in that link, then reverted when that didn't work

Comment: Before you reverted, did it work (did it change the setting (even if it didn't save))?

Comment: No, as far as I could tell it didn't make a difference to my settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here appeared to be the Nvidia save settings was writing and adding my screen name in front of the settings when saved. I ran the command that wizlog suggested `nvidia-settings -l` from the command line and got an output similar to [this](http://pastebin.com/kqWcu7ws). I've then gone about finding out why the errors were occuring, and found out that simply changing all of the `hostname:0.0` to simply 0 fixed this

Big thanks to [wizlog](https://superuser.com/users/81403/wizlog) for his persistence in this, and although didn't give the answer, certainly provided a basis for me to figure it out!

Comment: I hope you've had a pleasant experience on Super User.  Please don't hesitate to come back when you need help, or when you want to help others.

Answer (score 3):

Add **`nvidia-settings -l`** (this is a l as in load-settings, not an I as in Intention) 
to your desktop autostart. Read your desktop-environment / window-manager manual in order to find out where your autostart is.

-This worked 100% for [IndyUK](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/member.php?u=114459) who seems to have had the [exact same problem](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=144277).
[Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1406740) also has a [similar question](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1406740), which was solved the same way mentioned above.

Comment: That only enables or disables overscan being possible from the looks of it. I want to be able to set the value of the overscan compenasation. This has had no effect on the actual overscan compensation value

Comment: Once overscan "becomes possible", what is its default value?

Comment: Have you tried it?  If it works, you can simply have it start each time Ubuntu boots.

Comment: I have overscan showing in the nvidia configuration anyway, that's not an issue. The problem is getting the overscan compensation to save. I tried the above yes and it didn't fix anything

Comment: Look at my answer again, I changed it.